# Optimal solution for traversing random grids on a board by 2 players

Tags: algorithm

Consider an infinite 2D board. We have two players at points P1 and P2 on the board. They need to traverse a sequence of boxes on the board G1, G2, G3 .... Gn.

At the start only G1 is known. The coordinates of G2 to Gn are not known only after the box previous to it has been traversed. The players can move one at a time in one of the 8 possible directions on the board in unit time. We need to find the minimum time to traverse all required boxes using the two players.

The obvious solution is a greedy approach where the player nearer to the box that needs to be traversed moves towards it. Then we calculate the nearer player again for the next G. I feel a better solution exists to this problem that I cannot get my head around right now. Does a better solution exist?

Comment: If position of G1 is not known, so how is your greedy approach work? Furthermore, If a position is visited before, is this counted if that position is also where one of the box is located?

Comment: G1 is known of course at the start. No you need to revisit ofcourse. You could think of it like a snake game where the players need to collect food appearing at random places.

Comment: You don't say explicitly, so I'll ask. When P1 gets to G1, P1 *and* P2 then know the location of G2?

Comment: What's the probability distribution from which the Gi are drawn? It can't really be uniform because then the expected distance between the Gi would be infinite. Are the Gi chosen independently from each other and independent from the player positions

Comment: To be more precise, you cannot define a uniform distribution on an infinite, discrete parameter space

Comment: From one of your comments to an answer I understood that whenever a new box appears you decide which player moves and this player moves all the way to the box while the other player is not moved. Is this correct? If yes, please add it to the question.

Comment: @lex82 I had already mentioned that in the question. `The players can move one at a time`.

Comment: @NiklasB. I though so as well. The person who posed this question did not. His conviction made me believe there was an alternate way. No I cannot ask that person anymore (it was an interview).

Comment: @Sohaib As I said, there is no uniform distribution on this given space.  So this question is not well-posed. It wouldn't be the first interviewer to misstate a question or forget to mention an important detail. If however the person did include some more details in order to convince you that there is a solution, please include those details here

Answer (score 0):

I think as the board is infinite we should try to cover as much area with both players within n moves as possible (for every n). This way we maximize the abound of fields we can reach within n moves.

So my strategy would be:

Who is next to the next box?

Let this be P1.

Let P1 go to the box (shortest path) and go with the other player P2 in the directly opposite direction. This way we maximize the distance between the two players which minimizes the overlapping of the area they can reach in n steps. This way we maximize the coverage of the area the two players can reach in n steps for the next box.

Comment: Thing is at one time only one player can move. I was thinking of this strategy but how do we prove if this strategy is better?

Comment: If only one of then can move, I would go for the greedy approch. As Far as it concerns to proof that the strategy is better, I ave no idea. I would go for a simulation and compare the results for different strategies.

Comment: I don't think you can prove that your heuristic is useful. When P1 is moving towards G2, you have no information about the location of G3. Blindly moving P2 in the exact opposite direction of P2 is just as likely to move it *away* from G3 as towards G3. Because players can only move one at a time, then any anticipatory move that proves incorrect increases the total time and gives no benefit. So you might as well keep the other player stationary while the other is moving towards a known goal.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing the player closest to the next box is the best heuristic you can find.

**Explanation:** Whenever a new goal appears, there are only two options: Move player 1 or player 2 to the goal at the cost of the distance in fields. We also prefer a situation where players are far apart in contrast to close together. The most extreme case would be that both players are on the same field which is as good as having only one player. Since the playing field is infinite, being far apart is always better.

If this is correct, then you should ask yourself: Should I really choose the player being further away from the goal **and** end up in a situation where the players are closer together than they would have been if I had taken the other player?

Certainly not. In an infinite field, choosing the closest player helps with both, minimizing the current cost and improving the situation for the next goal (players far apart).

Comment: Whereas you're right that choosing the closest player is the best option, the reason you do it is because you have limited information on which to base a decision. It might actually be useful to move the player that's further away, because all the remaining points are clustered near the other player's current position. But because you don't know what's next, you take the greedy algorithm.

Comment: @jim-mischel Sure, if you knew all the positions you would have a nice optimization problem with an optimal solution that might not be obtained with the greedy approach. I assumed that it is clear that we are dealing with a heuristic here.

Answer (score -1):

Since the problem is non deterministic, the solution must be heuristic.

The "price" at each turn is the number of moves taken in the turn. This can be *PrN1* or *PrN2* for the number of moves for player1 or player2 respectively in turn N.

The "score" at each turn can be thought of as the probability that a certain arrangement (the position of both players) after the moves will be a good arrangement for the rest of the turns.

You'd want to use an evaluation function that considers both price and score to make the decision.

The problem is, the only useful scoring function is one that is some function of the distance between the players (the larger the distance, the greater the chance of being closer to the next turns) and this is exactly in sync with the minimum price. Any choice that keeps the players as far apart as possible is necessarily the one that was cheapest to make.

What all that means if that the best algorithm is simply to move the closest player, which is the first instinct you had.

Had the board *not* been infinite, you could create a better scoring function, one that considers the probabilities of the next boxes which would give lower scores to arrangements that leave a player on the edges of the board.

Comment: The board is infinite in length. I guess scoring is right but how to score and penalise is the part I cannot think of.

Comment: @Sohaib - I missed the point of infinite board. In that case, "value" is always the same - you can't compare two arrangements. This means you're really left just with "price", and that's what you suggested in the question itself.

Comment: Your assertion that "the larger the distance [between the players], the greater the chance of being closer to the next turns" is not true. For every example you can give where the players being maximally far apart is a benefit, I can give you one in which having the players closer together is better.

Comment: @JimMischel - but that's not how you measure probability. in the infinite board described, where the next box can be anywhere (with uniform probability for all cells), being further apart reduces the average distance from the next box. Consider a variation of this on a 1D line: If the players are at Cp1 & Cp2, does maximizing the distance between Cp1 & Cp2 reduce the average distance from the next spot? (yes, it does)